# Зачем нужны Thrift, COM, CORBA, STOMP?

Tags: php, java, c#, c++, node.js

На wiki очень сложно понять зачем нужны эти вещи. 
Понял что для взаимодействия разных программных компонент(к примеру одна часть работает на Java, другая на C#).

Все подобные задачи которые способен представить я могу решить с использованием HTTP или RabbitMQ.
Понятно что если будет задача поддерживать коммуникацию с помощью Thrift, COM, CORBA или STOMP буду применять. Но есть ли другие случаи применения?

Comment: Случаев много, какой имеется ввиду?

Comment: Мгм. Вы понимаете, что когда-то не было rabbit, а был только COM? А потом появился CORBA? И "я сейчас это делаю на такой-то технологии" невозможно было двадцать лет назад? И некоторые вещи прижились в крупных системах, они обладают изрядной инерцией и менять их никто не будет, потому что работает, а выкидывать кучу человеко-часов просто так нет бизнес-потребности.

Comment: Roman C , нет случая. Есть только желание понять зачем нужны эти названия. Возможно есть хорошая статья, которая раскроет тему.

Comment: Ваш вопрос достаточно общий и неконкретный для so, правда. Даже если разбить на отдельные вопросы (ком отдельно, корба отдельно и т.п.)

Comment: A K, ты хочешь сказать что это просто legacy и сейчас уже есть вещи которые полностью заменяют эти технологии(можно про каждый случай отдельно сказать)?

Comment: Вопрос в духе "Зачем нужны руки, ноги, хвост?.."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Объяснение многообразия инструментов решения одной и той же задачи:**

Каждая технология решает конкретную задачу для своего времени.

Например, Microsoft придумали COM решая задачу взаимодействия модулей на разных ЯП. Прошли годы и кто-то посмотрел на то во что эволюцинировал COM и придумал свое решение с оглядкой на проблемы COM'a.

Такая же тема и с появлением ЯП: авторы C# посмотрели на проблемы С++ и Java и учили эти ошибки при проектировании своего языка.

**Нафиг оно нужно?**

Никто в здравом уме не будет переписывать то, что работает => нужна обратная совместимость.

Все предерживаются парадигмы, что повторно используемый код- это круто.